# UITableView correct animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

The matter is, I want to have a grouped table view, and when I click on a cell, I want to have an another cell to appear under it, and so on. Everything is fine with workflow, but I have same problems with animations. It works very slowly and I can see all changes

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"selected section:%d selected row:%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);

    NSIndexPath* pathToDelete;

    [_tableView beginUpdates];
    if (_selectedPath != nil && [_selectedPath isEqual:indexPath]){
        //If the same row was selected
        pathToDelete = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_selectedPath.row+1 inSection:_selectedPath.section];
        _selectedPath = nil;
        [_tableView beginUpdates];
        [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:pathToDelete] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [_tableView endUpdates];

    } else {
        //If not
        if (_selectedPath != indexPath){
            //delete the row that we selected last time
            if (_selectedPath != nil){
                pathToDelete = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_selectedPath.row inSection:_selectedPath.section];
                [_tableView beginUpdates];
                [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:pathToDelete] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                [_tableView endUpdates];
            }

            //add new row in the section we selected
            _selectedPath = indexPath;
            [_tableView beginUpdates];
            [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
            [_tableView endUpdates];
        }
    }
    [_tableView beginUpdates];
    [_tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    [_tableView endUpdates];

    [_tableView reloadSections:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:pathToDelete.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
    [_tableView reloadSections:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:_selectedPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
    [_tableView endUpdates];
}
```

I think the problem is with begin & endUpdates method, but I don't know where exactly. Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this much simpler, by using a single `beginUpdates` - `endUpdates`. You just make your deletions and insertions inside of it. Don`t forget to update the data source for the table, otherwise the app will crash.

Hope this helps!